# How to use the new SlidingPaneLayout?

Tags: android

In the 13th revision of the v4 support library, google introduced the SlidingPaneLayout.
I don't know how should I start implementing it, and the documentation doesn't really seem to help. Could someone please clarify this to me?

Comment: Did you tried implementing yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [samples page](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Samples) - it'll point to your own installation. In particular, take a look at:

```
<sdk>\samples\Support4Demos\src\com\example\android\supportv4\widget\SlidingPaneLayoutActivity.java
```

I've just been playing with that example, converting it to use ActionBarSherlock - works a treat. Now working on how to integrate it with my current app.

Comment: I don't have this folder structure in my ADT SDK's "samples" folder